# Cannot install HTTPBuilder

Tags: groovy, httpbuilder

I'm trying to install `HTTPBuilder` like this:

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.7.2')
```

However, I'm getting this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error grabbing Grapes -- [download failed: commons-lang#commons-lang;2.4!commons-lang.jar]

```
$ grape -V resolve org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder http-builder 0.7.2
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/home/zoran/.gvm/groovy/2.4.4/lib/ivy-2.4.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
no default ivy user dir defined: set to /home/zoran/.ivy2
including url: jar:file:/home/zoran/.gvm/groovy/2.4.4/lib/ivy-2.4.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings-public.xml
no default cache defined: set to /home/zoran/.ivy2/cache
including url: jar:file:/home/zoran/.gvm/groovy/2.4.4/lib/ivy-2.4.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings-shared.xml
including url: jar:file:/home/zoran/.gvm/groovy/2.4.4/lib/ivy-2.4.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings-local.xml
including url: jar:file:/home/zoran/.gvm/groovy/2.4.4/lib/ivy-2.4.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings-main-chain.xml
including url: jar:file:/home/zoran/.gvm/groovy/2.4.4/lib/ivy-2.4.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings-default-chain.xml
settings loaded (22ms)
    default cache: /home/zoran/.ivy2/cache
    default resolver: default
    -- 5 resolvers:
    shared [file]
    default [chain] [local, main]
    local [file]
    public [ibiblio]
    main [chain] [shared, public]
:: resolving dependencies :: caller#all-caller;working93
    confs: [default]
    validate = false
    refresh = false
resolving dependencies for configuration 'default'
== resolving dependencies for caller#all-caller;working93 [default]
== resolving dependencies caller#all-caller;working93->org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.7.2 [default->default]
downloadGrapes: Checking cache for: dependency: org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.7.2 {default=[default]}
downloadGrapes: module revision found in cache: org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.7.2
    found org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.7.2 in jcenter
== resolving dependencies caller#all-caller;working93->org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.7.2 [default->runtime]
== resolving dependencies caller#all-caller;working93->org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.7.2 [default->compile]
== resolving dependencies org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.7.2->org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.1 [compile->master(*)]
downloadGrapes: Checking cache for: dependency: org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.1 {compile=[compile(*), master(*)], runtime=[runtime(*)]}
downloadGrapes: module revision found in cache: org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.1
    found org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.1 in localm2
== resolving dependencies org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.7.2->org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.1 [compile->compile(*)]
== resolving dependencies org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.1->org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.2.1 [compile->master(*)]
downloadGrapes: Checking cache for: dependency: org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.2.1 {compile=[compile(*), master(*)], runtime=[runtime(*)]}
downloadGrapes: module revision found in cache: org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.2.1
    found org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.2.1 in localm2
== resolving dependencies org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.1->org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.2.1 [compile->compile(*)]
== resolving dependencies org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.1->commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1 [compile->master(*)]
downloadGrapes: Checking cache for: dependency: commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1 {compile=[compile(*), master(*)], runtime=[runtime(*)]}
downloadGrapes: module revision found in cache: commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1
    found commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1 in localm2
dependency descriptor has been mediated: dependency: junit#junit;3.8.1 {test=[runtime(*), master(*)]} => dependency: junit#junit;4.9 {test=[runtime(*), master(*)]}
== resolving dependencies org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.1->commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1 [compile->compile(*)]
dependency descriptor has been mediated: dependency: junit#junit;3.8.1 {test=[runtime(*), master(*)]} => dependency: junit#junit;4.9 {test=[runtime(*), master(*)]}
== resolving dependencies org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.1->commons-codec#commons-codec;1.6 [compile->master(*)]
downloadGrapes: Checking cache for: dependency: commons-codec#commons-codec;1.6 {compile=[compile(*), master(*)], runtime=[runtime(*)]}
downloadGrapes: module revision found in cache: commons-codec#commons-codec;1.6
    found commons-codec#commons-codec;1.6 in localm2
dependency descriptor has been mediated: dependency: junit#junit;4.10 {test=[runtime(*), master(*)]} => dependency: junit#junit;4.9 {test=[runtime(*), master(*)]}
== resolving dependencies org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.1->commons-codec#commons-codec;1.6 [compile->compile(*)]
dependency descriptor has been mediated: dependency: junit#junit;4.10 {test=[runtime(*), master(*)]} => dependency: junit#junit;4.9 {test=[runtime(*), master(*)]}
== resolving dependencies org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.7.2->org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.1 [compile->runtime(*)]
== resolving dependencies org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.7.2->org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.1 [compile->compile]
== resolving dependencies org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.1->org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.2.1 [runtime->runtime(*)]
== resolving dependencies org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.1->org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.2.1 [runtime->compile]
== resolving dependencies org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.1->commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1 [runtime->runtime(*)]
== resolving dependencies org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.1->commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1 [runtime->compile]
dependency descriptor has been mediated: dependency: junit#junit;3.8.1 {test=[runtime(*), master(*)]} => dependency: junit#junit;4.9 {test=[runtime(*), master(*)]}
== resolving dependencies org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.1->commons-codec#commons-codec;1.6 [runtime->runtime(*)]
== resolving dependencies org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.1->commons-codec#commons-codec;1.6 [runtime->compile]
dependency descriptor has been mediated: dependency: junit#junit;4.10 {test=[runtime(*), master(*)]} => dependency: junit#junit;4.9 {test=[runtime(*), master(*)]}
== resolving dependencies org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.7.2->net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.3 [compile->master(*)]
downloadGrapes: Checking cache for: dependency: net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.3 {compile=[compile(*), master(*)], runtime=[runtime(*)]}
downloadGrapes: module revision found in cache: net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.3
    found net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.3 in localm2
== resolving dependencies org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.7.2->net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.3 [compile->compile(*)]
== resolving dependencies net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.3->commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils;1.8.0 [compile->master(*)]
downloadGrapes: Checking cache for: dependency: commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils;1.8.0 {compile=[compile(*), master(*)], runtime=[runtime(*)]}
downloadGrapes: module revision found in cache: commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils;1.8.0
    found commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils;1.8.0 in localm2
== resolving dependencies net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.3->commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils;1.8.0 [compile->compile(*)]
== resolving dependencies commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils;1.8.0->commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1 [compile->master(*)]
== resolving dependencies commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils;1.8.0->commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1 [compile->compile(*)]
== resolving dependencies net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.3->commons-collections#commons-collections;3.2.1 [compile->master(*)]
downloadGrapes: Checking cache for: dependency: commons-collections#commons-collections;3.2.1 {compile=[compile(*), master(*)], runtime=[runtime(*)]}
downloadGrapes: module revision found in cache: commons-collections#commons-collections;3.2.1
    found commons-collections#commons-collections;3.2.1 in localm2
== resolving dependencies net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.3->commons-collections#commons-collections;3.2.1 [compile->compile(*)]
== resolving dependencies net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.3->commons-lang#commons-lang;2.4 [compile->master(*)]
downloadGrapes: Checking cache for: dependency: commons-lang#commons-lang;2.4 {compile=[compile(*), master(*)], runtime=[runtime(*)]}
downloadGrapes: module revision found in cache: commons-lang#commons-lang;2.4
    found commons-lang#commons-lang;2.4 in localm2
== resolving dependencies net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.3->commons-lang#commons-lang;2.4 [compile->compile(*)]
== resolving dependencies net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.3->commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1 [compile->master(*)]
== resolving dependencies net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.3->commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1 [compile->compile(*)]
== resolving dependencies net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.3->net.sf.ezmorph#ezmorph;1.0.6 [compile->master(*)]
downloadGrapes: Checking cache for: dependency: net.sf.ezmorph#ezmorph;1.0.6 {compile=[compile(*), master(*)], runtime=[runtime(*)]}
downloadGrapes: module revision found in cache: net.sf.ezmorph#ezmorph;1.0.6
    found net.sf.ezmorph#ezmorph;1.0.6 in localm2
== resolving dependencies net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.3->net.sf.ezmorph#ezmorph;1.0.6 [compile->compile(*)]
== resolving dependencies net.sf.ezmorph#ezmorph;1.0.6->commons-lang#commons-lang;2.3 [compile->master(*)]
== resolving dependencies net.sf.ezmorph#ezmorph;1.0.6->commons-lang#commons-lang;2.4 [compile->master(*)]
== resolving dependencies net.sf.ezmorph#ezmorph;1.0.6->commons-lang#commons-lang;2.3 [compile->compile(*)]
== resolving dependencies net.sf.ezmorph#ezmorph;1.0.6->commons-lang#commons-lang;2.4 [compile->compile(*)]
== resolving dependencies org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.7.2->net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.3 [compile->runtime(*)]
== resolving dependencies org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.7.2->net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.3 [compile->compile]
== resolving dependencies net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.3->commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils;1.8.0 [runtime->runtime(*)]
== resolving dependencies net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.3->commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils;1.8.0 [runtime->compile]
== resolving dependencies commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils;1.8.0->commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1 [runtime->runtime(*)]
== resolving dependencies commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils;1.8.0->commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1 [runtime->compile]
== resolving dependencies net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.3->commons-collections#commons-collections;3.2.1 [runtime->runtime(*)]
== resolving dependencies net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.3->commons-collections#commons-collections;3.2.1 [runtime->compile]
== resolving dependencies net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.3->commons-lang#commons-lang;2.4 [runtime->runtime(*)]
== resolving dependencies net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.3->commons-lang#commons-lang;2.4 [runtime->compile]
== resolving dependencies net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.3->commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1 [runtime->runtime(*)]
== resolving dependencies net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.3->commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1 [runtime->compile]
== resolving dependencies net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.3->net.sf.ezmorph#ezmorph;1.0.6 [runtime->runtime(*)]
== resolving dependencies net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.3->net.sf.ezmorph#ezmorph;1.0.6 [runtime->compile]
== resolving dependencies net.sf.ezmorph#ezmorph;1.0.6->commons-lang#commons-lang;2.3 [runtime->runtime(*)]
== resolving dependencies net.sf.ezmorph#ezmorph;1.0.6->commons-lang#commons-lang;2.4 [runtime->runtime(*)]
== resolving dependencies net.sf.ezmorph#ezmorph;1.0.6->commons-lang#commons-lang;2.4 [runtime->compile]
== resolving dependencies org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.7.2->net.sourceforge.nekohtml#nekohtml;1.9.16 [compile->master(*)]
downloadGrapes: Checking cache for: dependency: net.sourceforge.nekohtml#nekohtml;1.9.16 {compile=[compile(*), master(*)], runtime=[runtime(*)]}
downloadGrapes: module revision found in cache: net.sourceforge.nekohtml#nekohtml;1.9.16
    found net.sourceforge.nekohtml#nekohtml;1.9.16 in localm2
== resolving dependencies org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.7.2->net.sourceforge.nekohtml#nekohtml;1.9.16 [compile->compile(*)]
== resolving dependencies net.sourceforge.nekohtml#nekohtml;1.9.16->xerces#xercesImpl;2.9.1 [compile->master(*)]
downloadGrapes: Checking cache for: dependency: xerces#xercesImpl;2.9.1 {compile=[compile(*), master(*)], runtime=[runtime(*)]}
downloadGrapes: module revision found in cache: xerces#xercesImpl;2.9.1
    found xerces#xercesImpl;2.9.1 in localm2
== resolving dependencies net.sourceforge.nekohtml#nekohtml;1.9.16->xerces#xercesImpl;2.9.1 [compile->compile(*)]
== resolving dependencies xerces#xercesImpl;2.9.1->xml-apis#xml-apis;1.3.04 [compile->master(*)]
downloadGrapes: Checking cache for: dependency: xml-apis#xml-apis;1.3.04 {compile=[compile(*), master(*)], runtime=[runtime(*)]}
downloadGrapes: module revision found in cache: xml-apis#xml-apis;1.3.04
    found xml-apis#xml-apis;1.3.04 in jcenter
== resolving dependencies xerces#xercesImpl;2.9.1->xml-apis#xml-apis;1.3.04 [compile->compile(*)]
== resolving dependencies org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.7.2->net.sourceforge.nekohtml#nekohtml;1.9.16 [compile->runtime(*)]
== resolving dependencies org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.7.2->net.sourceforge.nekohtml#nekohtml;1.9.16 [compile->compile]
== resolving dependencies net.sourceforge.nekohtml#nekohtml;1.9.16->xerces#xercesImpl;2.9.1 [runtime->runtime(*)]
== resolving dependencies net.sourceforge.nekohtml#nekohtml;1.9.16->xerces#xercesImpl;2.9.1 [runtime->compile]
== resolving dependencies xerces#xercesImpl;2.9.1->xml-apis#xml-apis;1.3.04 [runtime->runtime(*)]
== resolving dependencies xerces#xercesImpl;2.9.1->xml-apis#xml-apis;1.3.04 [runtime->compile]
== resolving dependencies org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.7.2->xml-resolver#xml-resolver;1.2 [compile->master(*)]
downloadGrapes: Checking cache for: dependency: xml-resolver#xml-resolver;1.2 {compile=[compile(*), master(*)], runtime=[runtime(*)]}
downloadGrapes: module revision found in cache: xml-resolver#xml-resolver;1.2
    found xml-resolver#xml-resolver;1.2 in localm2
== resolving dependencies org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.7.2->xml-resolver#xml-resolver;1.2 [compile->compile(*)]
== resolving dependencies org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.7.2->xml-resolver#xml-resolver;1.2 [compile->runtime(*)]
== resolving dependencies org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.7.2->xml-resolver#xml-resolver;1.2 [compile->compile]
== resolving dependencies org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.7.2->org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.1 [runtime->runtime(*)]
== resolving dependencies org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.7.2->org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.1 [runtime->compile]
== resolving dependencies org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.7.2->net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.3 [runtime->runtime(*)]
== resolving dependencies org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.7.2->net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.3 [runtime->compile]
== resolving dependencies org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.7.2->net.sourceforge.nekohtml#nekohtml;1.9.16 [runtime->runtime(*)]
== resolving dependencies org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.7.2->net.sourceforge.nekohtml#nekohtml;1.9.16 [runtime->compile]
== resolving dependencies org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.7.2->xml-resolver#xml-resolver;1.2 [runtime->runtime(*)]
== resolving dependencies org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.7.2->xml-resolver#xml-resolver;1.2 [runtime->compile]
== resolving dependencies caller#all-caller;working93->org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.7.2 [default->master]
    resolved ivy file produced in cache
:: downloading artifacts ::
    [NOT REQUIRED] org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.7.2!http-builder.jar
    [NOT REQUIRED] org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.1!httpclient.jar
    [NOT REQUIRED] net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.3!json-lib.jar
    [NOT REQUIRED] net.sourceforge.nekohtml#nekohtml;1.9.16!nekohtml.jar
    [NOT REQUIRED] xml-resolver#xml-resolver;1.2!xml-resolver.jar
    [NOT REQUIRED] org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.2.1!httpcore.jar
    [NOT REQUIRED] commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1!commons-logging.jar
    [NOT REQUIRED] commons-codec#commons-codec;1.6!commons-codec.jar
    [NOT REQUIRED] commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils;1.8.0!commons-beanutils.jar
    [NOT REQUIRED] commons-collections#commons-collections;3.2.1!commons-collections.jar
        tried file:/home/zoran/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/commons-lang-2.4.jar
WARN:   [NOT FOUND  ] commons-lang#commons-lang;2.4!commons-lang.jar (2ms)
WARN: ==== localm2: tried
WARN:   file:/home/zoran/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/commons-lang-2.4.jar
    [NOT REQUIRED] net.sf.ezmorph#ezmorph;1.0.6!ezmorph.jar
    [NOT REQUIRED] xerces#xercesImpl;2.9.1!xercesImpl.jar
    [NOT REQUIRED] xml-apis#xml-apis;1.3.04!xml-apis.jar
    resolve done (332ms resolve - 18ms download)

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        [NOT FOUND  ] commons-lang#commons-lang;2.4!commons-lang.jar (2ms)

    ==== localm2: tried

      file:/home/zoran/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/commons-lang-2.4.jar


:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
Error in resolve:
    Error grabbing Grapes -- [download failed: commons-lang#commons-lang;2.4!commons-lang.jar]
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Ever since CodeHaus folded, things have been weird. I tried `@Grab` back to older versions at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/http-builder but upstream dependencies failed there also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deleting `~/.groovy/grapes` did it. Don't know why tho...

Comment: Same here. Deleting contents of ~/.m2 was not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you had commons-lang in your `.m2` repo but the jar was not there (only the pom).

The fix is to remove common-lang folder from `.m2` repo and `.groovy/grape`s and rerun the script or resolve using this command:

```
grape -V resolve commons-lang commons-lang 2.4
```

Comment: Got java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException. Have never seen a call stack this deep.