# Jenkins pipeline - How to give choice parameters dynamically

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage("foo") {
        steps {
            script {
                env.RELEASE_SCOPE = input message: 'User input required', ok: 'Release!',
                        parameters: [choice(name: 'RELEASE_SCOPE', choices: 'patch\nminor\nmajor', 
                                     description: 'What is the release scope?')]
            }
            echo "${env.RELEASE_SCOPE}"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

In this above code, The choice are hardcoded (patch\nminor\nmajor) -- My requirement is to dynamically give choice values in the dropdown.
I get the values from calling api - Artifacts list (.zip) file names from artifactory
In the above example, It request input when we do the build, But i want to do a "Build with parameters"

Please suggest/help on this.

Comment: What api do u use or where are the api values stored?

Comment: I am using artifactory api and values are stored in the file - and calling them to a variable by reading the file.
I am trying to learn and need a better way. I need to populate values from repo to choice/Active choice parameter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call REST from jenkins workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34682099/how-to-call-rest-from-jenkins-workflow)

Answer (score 7):

Depends how you get data from API there will be different options for it, for example let's imagine that you get data as a List of Strings (let's call it releaseScope), in that case your code be following:

```
...
script {
    def releaseScopeChoices = ''
    releaseScope.each {
        releaseScopeChoices += it + '\n'
    }

    parameters: [choice(name: 'RELEASE_SCOPE', choices: ${releaseScopeChoices}, description: 'What is the release scope?')]
}
...
```

hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks a lot. May be that is what i need. Here is my api call and how i used to store the list of values 
I have a artifactory repo, and it has list of zip file which i want to populate in the choice/active choice parameter
Below is the code i used

Comment: pipeline {
    agent { label 'Linuxnode' }
    stages {
        stage("call api") {
            steps {
                script {
  sh '''#!/usr/bin/sh
  VAR=$(curl -s -X POST -k -u uname:pwd \'https://artifactory.com/artifactory/api/search/aql\' -d \'items.find({"repo":"datasources-local"})\')
  echo $VAR | python -c \'import json,sys; 
  obj=json.load(sys.stdin); 
  for i in range(len(obj["results"])):
      print obj["results"][i]["name"]\' >> k.txt'''
      env.WORKSPACE = pwd()
def p = readFile "${env.WORKSPACE}/k.txt"
      println(p)
                             }
}

Comment: in the above code p - variable will have the list of zip files - i want to populate them to the choice parameter.. please help on this.

Comment: you are trying to do all in shell scriptiing, that's wonderful, but let me make your life a bit easier - Jenkins Pipeline let you use Groovy , so consider using that, which in your case will be much easier nicer code and all in the same place and you will not need to use system vars.

Comment: also, please, if the answer is correct mark it correct

Comment: Sure.. that helps if you can give something for Jenkins pipeline. Marked correct :)

Comment: Hi BigGinDaHouse -- Did you get chance to look into this and give a better script in groovy...

Comment: Nope, I did not, sorry

Answer (score 5):

This is a cutdown version of what we use. We separate stuff into shared libraries but I have consolidated a bit to make it easier.

Jenkinsfile looks something like this:

```
#!groovy
@Library('shared') _
def imageList = pipelineChoices.artifactoryArtifactSearchList(repoName, env.BRANCH_NAME)
imageList.add(0, 'build')
properties([
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '20')),
    parameters([
        choice(name: 'ARTIFACT_NAME', choices: imageList.join('\n'), description: '')
    ])
])
```

Shared library that looks at artifactory, its pretty simple.
Essentially make GET Request (And provide auth creds on it) then filter/split result to whittle down to desired values and return list to Jenkinsfile.

```
import com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.NonCPS
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import java.util.regex.Pattern
import java.util.regex.Matcher   

List artifactoryArtifactSearchList(String repoKey, String artifact_name, String artifact_archive, String branchName) {
    // URL components
    String baseUrl = "https://org.jfrog.io/org/api/search/artifact"
    String url = baseUrl + "?name=${artifact_name}&repos=${repoKey}"

    Object responseJson = getRequest(url)

    String regexPattern = "(.+)${artifact_name}-(\\d+).(\\d+).(\\d+).${artifact_archive}\$"

    Pattern regex = ~ regexPattern
    List<String> outlist = responseJson.results.findAll({ it['uri'].matches(regex) })
    List<String> artifactlist=[]

    for (i in outlist) {
        artifactlist.add(i['uri'].tokenize('/')[-1])
    }

    return artifactlist.reverse()
}

// Artifactory Get Request - Consume in other methods
Object getRequest(url_string){

    URL url = url_string.toURL()

    // Open connection
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection()

    connection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuthString())

    // Open input stream
    InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream()
    @NonCPS
    json_data = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(inputStream.text)
    // Close the stream
    inputStream.close()

    return json_data
}

// Artifactory Get Request - Consume in other methods
Object basicAuthString() {
    // Retrieve password
    String username = "artifactoryMachineUsername"
    String credid = "artifactoryApiKey"
    @NonCPS
    credentials_store = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getExtensionList(
        'com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider'
        )
    credentials_store[0].credentials.each { it ->
        if (it instanceof org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.StringCredentials) {
            if (it.getId() == credid) {
                apiKey = it.getSecret()
            }
        }
    }
    // Create authorization header format using Base64 encoding
    String userpass = username + ":" + apiKey;
    String basicAuth = "Basic " + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userpass.getBytes());

    return basicAuth

}
```

Comment: I am trying the above script you gave.. but i dont have admin access to put in the library and i am getting "peer not authenticated" error when trying to list artifacts using groovy. I previously tried curl with -k option. That would be great if you can give me a script without library and for Active choice parameters

Comment: Just define the same methods in your jenkinsfile, then you don't need to call out to shared libs.

Comment: @metalisticpain will you be kind enough to explain where the `body.artifacts` come in  `choices: body.artifacts.join('\n')`. Also `pipelineChoices` and `imageList.add(0, 'build')`. I could not understand these. Thank you

Comment: Looking at this code a few years later and I think you have picked up a typo in my example.
Looks like I pieced it together to create a small example but some refs arnt correct.
`body.artifacts.join('\n')` should be `imageList.join('\n')`
`pipelineChoices` is the filename of the shared library that `artifactoryArtifactSearchList` function lives in. Thats just a call to it.

Comment: `imageList.add(0, 'build')` adds `build` to the returned list. So say my imageList returns `['image1', 'image2']`, then I add `build` at index 0. So it becomes `['build', 'image1', 'image2']`. I do this because the 'default' option for a choice param is the 1st value.

Answer (score 3):

I could achieve it without any plugin:

With Jenkins 2.249.2 using a declarative pipeline,
the following pattern prompt the user with a dynamic dropdown menu
(for him to choose a branch):

(the surrounding withCredentials bloc is optional, required only if your script and jenkins configuration do use credentials)

```
node {

    withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding',
                  credentialsId: 'user-credential-in-gitlab',
                  usernameVariable: 'GIT_USERNAME',
                  passwordVariable: 'GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN']]) {
        BRANCH_NAMES = sh (script: 'git ls-remote -h https://${GIT_USERNAME}:${GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN}@dns.name/gitlab/PROJS/PROJ.git | sed \'s/\\(.*\\)\\/\\(.*\\)/\\2/\' ', returnStdout:true).trim()
    }
}
pipeline {

    agent any

    parameters {
        choice(
            name: 'BranchName',
            choices: "${BRANCH_NAMES}",
            description: 'to refresh the list, go to configure, disable "this build has parameters", launch build (without parameters)to reload the list and stop it, then launch it again (with parameters)'
        )
    }

    stages {
        stage("Run Tests") {
            steps {
                sh "echo SUCCESS on ${BranchName}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The drawback is that one should refresh the jenkins configration and use a blank run for the list be refreshed using the script ...
Solution (not from me): This limitation can be made less anoying using an aditional parameters used to specifically refresh the values:

```
parameters {
        booleanParam(name: 'REFRESH_BRANCHES', defaultValue: false, description: 'refresh BRANCH_NAMES branch list and launch no step')
}
```

then wihtin stage:

```
stage('a stage') {
   when {
      expression { 
         return ! params.REFRESH_BRANCHES.toBoolean()
      }
   }
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this is my solution.

```
def envList
def dockerId
node {
    envList = "defaultValue\n" + sh (script: 'kubectl get namespaces --no-headers -o custom-columns=":metadata.name"', returnStdout: true).trim()
}
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        choice(choices: "${envList}", name: 'DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT', description: 'please choose the environment you want to deploy?')
        booleanParam(name: 'SECURITY_SCAN',defaultValue: false, description: 'container vulnerability scan')
    }
```

Comment: Yes, like me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67775090/1767316) to prompt for branch selection

Answer (score 0):

The example of Jenkinsfile below contains AWS CLI command to get the list of Docker images from AWS ECR dynamically, but it can be replaced with your own command. [Active Choices Plug-in](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/) is required.

**Note!** You need to approve the script specified in `parameters` after first run in "Manage Jenkins" -> "In-process Script Approval", or open job configuration and save it to approve 
automatically (might require administrator permissions).

```
properties([
  parameters([[
    $class: 'ChoiceParameter',
    choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
    name: 'image',
    description: 'Docker image',
    filterLength: 1,
    filterable: false,
    script: [
      $class: 'GroovyScript',
      fallbackScript: [classpath: [], sandbox: false, script: 'return ["none"]'],
      script: [
        classpath: [],
        sandbox: false,
        script: '''\
          def repository = "frontend"
          def aws_ecr_cmd = "aws ecr list-images" +
                            " --repository-name ${repository}" +
                            " --filter tagStatus=TAGGED" +
                            " --query imageIds[*].[imageTag]" +
                            " --region us-east-1 --output text"
          def aws_ecr_out = aws_ecr_cmd.execute() | "sort -V".execute()
          def images = aws_ecr_out.text.tokenize().reverse()
          return images
        '''.stripIndent()
      ]
    ]
  ]])
])

pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {  
    stage('First stage') {
      steps {
        sh 'echo "${image}"'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I had to use $class: 'ChoiceParameterDefinition' instead of ,$class: 'ChoiceParameter',  to avoid the following error: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: no known implementation of class hudson.model.ParameterDefinition is named ChoiceParameter  ( .... even If I have for now no value yet in my combo using def proc = 'git for-each-ref --format=\'%(refname:short)\' refs/heads/'.execute() to retrieve branch list) Also I found no script available for aproval in the dedicated admin page

Comment: and how would you do this if you need to use credentials?

Comment: I'm using IAM Role with proper permissions attached to Jenkins master instance, so no need to pass credentials directly to the script in this parameter.

Answer (score -4):

```
choiceArray = [ "patch" , "minor" , "major" ]

properties([
    parameters([
            choice(choices: choiceArray.collect { "$it\n" }.join(' ') ,
                    description: '',
                    name: 'SOME_CHOICE')

    ])
])
```

Comment: His choices are dynamic. Meaning he needs to make a network call. This does not answer the question

Comment: Code only answers are rarely useful. Please provide explanation

Comment: array is static meaning of data