# Active choice parameter with declarative Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I'm trying to use active choice parameter with declarative Jenkins Pipeline script.

This is my simple script:

```
environments = 'lab\nstage\npro'

properties([
    parameters([
        [$class: 'ChoiceParameter',
            choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
            description: 'Select a choice',
            filterLength: 1,
            filterable: true,
            name: 'choice1',
            randomName: 'choice-parameter-7601235200970',
            script: [$class: 'GroovyScript',
                fallbackScript: [classpath: [], sandbox: false, script: 'return ["ERROR"]'],
                script: [classpath: [], sandbox: false, 
                    script: """
                        if params.ENVIRONMENT == 'lab'
                            return['aaa','bbb']
                        else
                            return ['ccc', 'ddd']
                    """
                ]]]
    ])
])

pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {
        maven 'Maven 3.6'
    }
    options {
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
        timestamps()
        timeout(time: 30, unit: 'MINUTES')
        ansiColor('xterm')
    }
    parameters {
        choice(name: 'ENVIRONMENT', choices: "${environments}")
    }
    stages {
        stage("Run Tests") {
            steps {
                sh "echo SUCCESS on ${params.ENVIRONMENT}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But actually the second parameter is empty

[image]

Is it possible to use together scripted active choice parameter and declarative parameter?

**UPD**
Is there any way to pass list variable into script? For example

```
List<String> someList = ['ttt', 'yyyy']
...
script: [
    classpath: [], 
    sandbox: true, 
    script: """
        if (ENVIRONMENT == 'lab') { 
            return someList
        }
        else {
            return['ccc', 'ddd']
        }
    """.stripIndent()
]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use `Active Choices Reactive Parameter` which enable current job parameter to reference another job parameter value

```
environments = 'lab\nstage\npro'

properties([
    parameters([
        [$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter', 
            choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
            description: 'Select a choice',
            filterLength: 1,
            filterable: true,
            name: 'choice1',
            referencedParameters: 'ENVIRONMENT',
            script: [$class: 'GroovyScript',
                fallbackScript: [
                    classpath: [], 
                    sandbox: true, 
                    script: 'return ["ERROR"]'
                ],
                script: [
                    classpath: [], 
                    sandbox: true, 
                    script: """
                        if (ENVIRONMENT == 'lab') { 
                            return['aaa','bbb']
                        }
                        else {
                            return['ccc', 'ddd']
                        }
                    """.stripIndent()
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ])
])

pipeline {
    agent any

    options {
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
        timestamps()
        timeout(time: 30, unit: 'MINUTES')
        ansiColor('xterm')
    }
    parameters {
        choice(name: 'ENVIRONMENT', choices: "${environments}")
    }
    stages {
        stage("Run Tests") {
            steps {
                sh "echo SUCCESS on ${params.ENVIRONMENT}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately the `choice1` parameter is still empty.

Comment: Your original `if/else` block has syntax error,  missed `() and {}`, and  better set `sandbox: true` . Above Jenkinsfile had verified and work as expect on my local Jenkins job.

Comment: Excellent! It works. Many thanks. 
May you give advice, please (I updated post and added another question)?

Comment: Linked with a post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63093323/pass-groovy-object-into-active-choice-parameter

Comment: I have "no known implementation of class hudson.model.ParameterDefinition is named CascadeChoiceParameter"

Comment: then like  Marat Gareev if replacing CascadeChoiceParameter by  ChoiceParameterDefinition

Comment: ok "Active Choices Reactive Parameter" is a plugin, it probably provides this class

Answer (score 2):

As of Jenkins 2.249.2 without any plugin and using a declarative pipeline,
the following pattern prompt the user with a dynamic dropdown menu (for him to choose a branch):

(the surrounding withCredentials bloc is optional, required only if your script and jenkins configuratoin do use credentials)

node {

```
withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding',
              credentialsId: 'user-credential-in-gitlab',
              usernameVariable: 'GIT_USERNAME',
              passwordVariable: 'GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN']]) {
    BRANCH_NAMES = sh (script: 'git ls-remote -h https://${GIT_USERNAME}:${GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN}@dns.name/gitlab/PROJS/PROJ.git | sed \'s/\\(.*\\)\\/\\(.*\\)/\\2/\' ', returnStdout:true).trim()
}
```

}
pipeline {

```
agent any

parameters {
    choice(
        name: 'BranchName',
        choices: "${BRANCH_NAMES}",
        description: 'to refresh the list, go to configure, disable "this build has parameters", launch build (without parameters)to reload the list and stop it, then launch it again (with parameters)'
    )
}

stages {
    stage("Run Tests") {
        steps {
            sh "echo SUCCESS on ${BranchName}"
        }
    }
}
```

}

The drawback is that one should refresh the jenkins configration and use a blank run for the list be refreshed using the script ...

Solution (not from me): This limitation can be made less anoying using an aditional parameters used to specifically refresh the values:

```
parameters {
        booleanParam(name: 'REFRESH_BRANCHES', defaultValue: false, description: 'refresh BRANCH_NAMES branch list and launch no step')
}
```

then wihtin stage:

```
stage('a stage') {
   when {
      expression { 
         return ! params.REFRESH_BRANCHES.toBoolean()
      }
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: i wonder if this can be made dynamic, driven off of another choice selection box. i.e. another choice where the user can select the repository