# Pass Groovy object into active choice parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I use active choice reactive parameter with declarative pipeline. But I ran into a problem.

Is there any way to pass list object into script or call external method?

For example

```
environments = 'lab\nstage\npro'

List<String> someList = ['ccc', 'ddd']
def someMethod() { 
   return ['aaa', 'bbb']
}

properties([
    parameters([
        choice(name: 'ENVIRONMENT', choices: "${environments}"),
        [$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter', 
            choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
            description: 'Select a choice',
            filterLength: 1,
            filterable: true,
            name: 'choice1',
            referencedParameters: 'ENVIRONMENT',
            script: [$class: 'GroovyScript',
                fallbackScript: [
                    classpath: [], 
                    sandbox: true, 
                    script: 'return ["ERROR"]'
                ],
                script: [
                    classpath: [], 
                    sandbox: true, 
                    script: """
                        if (ENVIRONMENT == 'lab') { 
                            return someMethod() // !!! call method
                        }
                        else {
                            return someList // !!! return object
                        }
                    """.stripIndent()
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ])
])

pipeline {
    agent any
    ...
}
```

I would be grateful for any hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it by using string interpolation

```
List<String> someList = ['ccc', 'ddd']
def someMethod() { 
   return ['aaa', 'bbb']
}
...
script: """
    if (ENVIRONMENT == 'lab') { 
        return ["${someMethod().join('","')}"] // !!! call method
    }
    else {
        return ["${someList.join('","')}"] // !!! return object
    }
""".stripIndent()
```

**UPD**: a function call with an argument that is a job parameter.

In this case, the current solution will not work, since the argument variable will be searched for in the external context. You can replace it with *params.ParamName*:

```
return ["${someMethod(params.ParamName).join('","')}"]
```

but then its value will be *null*.

So, you have to put whole function into parameter script like this:

```
properties([
    parameters([
        [$class: 'ChoiceParameter',
            choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
            filterable: false,
            name: 'PartnerName',
            script: [$class: 'GroovyScript',
                fallbackScript: [
                    classpath: [],
                    sandbox: true,
                    script: 'return ["ERROR"]'
                ],
                script: [
                    classpath: [],
                    sandbox: true,
                    script: """
                        return ["single_partner"]
                    """.stripIndent()
                ]
            ]
        ],
        [$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter',
            choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
            filterLength: 1,
            filterable: false,
            name: 'AutoCalcParam',
            referencedParameters: 'PartnerName',
            script: [$class: 'GroovyScript',
                fallbackScript: [
                    classpath: [],
                    sandbox: true,
                    script: 'return ["ERROR"]'
                ],
                script: [
                    classpath: [],
                    sandbox: true,
                    script: """
                        def getGFEPartners(String partnerName) { 
                            return [partnerName+'_aaa', partnerName+'_bbb']
                        }
                        return getGFEPartners(PartnerName)
                         """.stripIndent()
                ]
            ]
        ],
```

And will see expected result:
[image]

Comment: I had the same questions, Thank you for this answer Marat it helped me. One mor question, The method def someMethod() { 
   return ['aaa', 'bbb']
} doesn't take any argument. If I want to send arguments to it, def someMethod(String partnerName) {if(partnerName =="etc" 
   return ['aaa', 'bbb']}
} method is not getting called and am getting error, roovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: partnerName. Coud you please help me how to call the method passing an argument as per the solution above?

Comment: Hi @SathishPrakasam , may you show how you call function? And where is the passed variable defined?

Comment: Am calling from the script section of CascadeChoiceParameter, 
          
            referencedParameters: 'PartnerName',
            script: [$class: 'GroovyScript',
                fallbackScript: [
                    classpath: [], 
                    sandbox: true, 
                    script: 'return ["ERROR"]'
                ],
                script: [
                    classpath: [], 
                    sandbox: true, 
                    script: """
                   return ["${getGFEPartners(PartnerName).join('","')}"]
                ]
            ]
        ]

Comment: The argumet is the name of the another active choice parameter.

Comment: I tried to explain the solution, please take a look at the updated post.

Answer (score 0):

In my tests, the only dynamic variable I manage to pass into the Groovy script enclosed in triple quotes, was one or more variables whose values are chosen by the user in the GUI of the Build with Parameter. This includes variables of type "ChoiceParameter" (as in the final script above of @Marat Gareev) and "CascadeChoiceParameter" (which is one of the types the Active Choice Plugin gives). Everything else doesn't work, not even the usual environment variables of a pipeline, such as the JOB_NAME or BUILD_NUMBER.

You can have the impression you are passing a "variable" to the Groovy script enclosed in triple quotes, as in the working example I show below, but you are not. Even if you use functions to build the scripts, the scripts are only built once, when you click in "Build with Parameters". This means that, for example, the `entriesPerInfoTypeScript` script below is created and loaded at the beginning, using the *constant* data the is available at that time (`namesList` and `agesList` in this case) and that's it. There is no dynamic behavior. For example, imagine that you want to query a git remote repository for its tags when you select `INFO_TYPE=name`, and another one when you select `INFO_TYPE=age`. And imagine that you want to put the tags you get in the answer in another drop down menu of the Active Choice parameter. You want this second drop down menu to change when you change the INFO_TYPE, and you want it also to update as people out there push new tags to those repos! This means that you would need to update a list like `List tagsInTargetRepo = ...` similar to the list `namesList` of the example, and pass it to the triple quoted Groovy script, in the body of a function like `getTagsInTargetRepoScript(...)`, hoping it will display it updated. I tried for one week to achieve that without success.

May be if I use `sandbox: false` I can access the usual Jenkins environment variables such as the JOB_NAME. But then I would have to manually approve in Jenkins each and every script that comes out from my script generating code (functions).

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
def doubleQuoteElements = { w -> '"' + w + '"' }

List infoTypeChoices = ['name', 'age'].collect(doubleQuoteElements)                        

List namesList = ['John', 'Carl'].collect(doubleQuoteElements)
List agesList = ['34', '29'].collect(doubleQuoteElements)

def getStaticListScript(List l) {
    return "return $l"
}

def getEntriesPerInfoType(List namesList, List agesList) {
    def entriesPerInfoType = """
                                if(INFO_TYPE.equals('name')) { return $namesList }                       
                                if(INFO_TYPE.equals('age')) { return $agesList }
                                else { return [''] }
                             """
    return entriesPerInfoType
}

infoTypeScript = getStaticListScript(infoTypeChoices)
entriesPerInfoTypeScript = getEntriesPerInfoType(namesList, agesList)

properties([
    parameters([
        [$class: 'ChoiceParameter', choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
        description: 'Type of information you want, ie. names or ages',
        name: 'INFO_TYPE',
        script: 
            [$class: 'GroovyScript',
            fallbackScript: [classpath: [], sandbox: true, script: 'return ["ERROR"]'],
            script: [classpath: [], sandbox: true, script: infoTypeScript]
            ]
        ],
        [$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter', choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
        description: 'Entries for the type of information you selected',
        name: 'ENTRY_PER_INFO_TYPE',
        referencedParameters: 'INFO_TYPE',
        script:
            [$class: 'GroovyScript',
            fallbackScript: [classpath: [], sandbox: false, script: 'return ["ERROR"]'],
            script: [classpath: [], sandbox: true, script: entriesPerInfoTypeScript]]
        ],

    ])
])

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage ("Print Inputs"){
            steps {
                script{
                    echo "printing inputs ..."
                    echo "INFO_TYPE: "+ INFO_TYPE
                    echo "ENTRY_PER_INFO_TYPE: "+ ENTRY_PER_INFO_TYPE

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```