# Deploy sub-folders of my SVN repository into 2 different MarkLogic DB based on the sub-folder name using Jenkins

Tags: marklogic

I have an XQuery repository and I have two child folders inside it (**folder1** and **folder2**). I want folder1 to be deployed to **Modules** DB in my MarkLogic server and folder2 to be deployed to **second-modules** DB.
How to achieve this using Jenkins?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Jenkins [HTTP Request Plugins](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/HTTP+Request+Plugin) to import the modules.  This will allow you to use the [MarkLogic REST API](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/v1/documents) to import the modules to whichever database you want.

For CI/CD MarkLogic also offers the [ml-gradle plugin](https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle), as well as the [Packaging API](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/packaging).  The Packaging API can be used via the HTTP Request Plugin.  ml-gradle can be used via the Jenkins Gradle plugin:

- https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Gradle+Plugin
- https://guides.gradle.org/executing-gradle-builds-on-jenkins/

And here is a related Stackoverflow question on [How to call REST from Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34682099/how-to-call-rest-from-jenkins-workflow)