# Call an API in a Groovy script with sandbox activated

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to load a list that is returned from an API into a Jenkins parameter. For this I'm using [uno-choice](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/) plugin and executing a Groovy script, because I want the parameter to appear depending on other existing parameters of the Jenkins job.

I have seen other plugins like [http-request](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/) and [rest-list-parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/rest-list-parameter/) but they don't work for me because the API response depends of the other parameters in the Jenkins job.

I have tested the solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34682099/how-to-call-rest-from-jenkins-workflow) and I was able to achieve what I wanted with **sandbox deactivated** when testing locally, but the Jenkins that my team uses has the **sandbox activated** and when I try to run the script again it fails without information or saying:

> Failed to evaluate script: Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod

Requesting my company to allow me to run the script is not a solution either.
Is it possible to call an API from groovy scripts with the sandbox activated?