# Groovy: No suitable ClassLoader found for grab

Tags: linux, groovy

I know there are like 10 other posts about this topic, but none of the answers work for me right now, not even [my own previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37559458/groovy-install-httpbuilder-now-that-codehaus-shutdown) when I ran into this before because that time it was working on my CentOS linux server just fine but was failing when I was running it from IntelliJ on my Mac.

Now I have the opposite problem. It's working on my Mac but not on my linux server. I've just migrated to a new CentOS 7 server and now it's not working when I run it from the command line on my CentOS 7 server.

Here is the stop of my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

@Grab('mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.25')
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader = true)

import groovy.sql.Sql
import groovy.util.GroovyScriptEngine

String reportdate
if (args.length > 0) {
        reportdate = args[0]

} else {
        def today = new Date()
        def yesterday = today - 1
        reportdate = yesterday.format("yyyy-MM-dd")
}
```

Here is the error output:

```
$ ./smart_daily_fetch.groovy 
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
General error during conversion: No suitable ClassLoader found for grab

java.lang.RuntimeException: No suitable ClassLoader found for grab
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
    at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy.chooseClassLoader(GrapeIvy.groovy:175)
    at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy$chooseClassLoader.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy.grab(GrapeIvy.groovy:241)
    at groovy.grape.Grape.grab(Grape.java:141)
    at groovy.grape.GrabAnnotationTransformation.visit(GrabAnnotationTransformation.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformationVisitor$3.call(ASTTransformationVisitor.java:308)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:846)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:550)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:526)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:503)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:302)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:281)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:267)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:197)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell$2.run(GroovyShell.java:215)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell$2.run(GroovyShell.java:213)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:213)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:159)
    at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.processOnce(GroovyMain.java:550)
    at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.run(GroovyMain.java:337)
    at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.process(GroovyMain.java:323)
    at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.processArgs(GroovyMain.java:120)
    at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.main(GroovyMain.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:130)

1 error
```

Comment: How did you install groovy? I suggest using sdkman. http://sdkman.io/

Comment: I used yum to install it. I took your advice, had yum remove groovy, installed sdkman, installed groovy with sdkman, and then groovy worked perfectly. Thank you! If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version that comes with the linux distributions and available on the repositories is usually way out of date. I recommend sdkman to manage the versions of groovy/gradle/grails and many other sdks.

Get it here:

http://sdkman.io/